What is the preferred way to block an IP address or range?
The website and forum I manage are constantly bombarded by spammers, crawlers and unwanted attention from countries that would have absolutely no interest in the topic of our site.
I know there are several ways to block IP addresses using IIS, web.config, .htaccess, as well as the built-in features of phpBB (for the forum) and robots.txt for crawlers (assuming they comply which one major company does not appear to do).
I was interested to see what others would do in this scenario and which option you would use ..
Yes, I know I am probably on a hiding to nothing, and face a constant battle, but there are the unscrupulous out there who don't comply with robots.txt, etc.
TIA

In dealing with the relentless spam, crawlers, and unwanted traffic from irrelevant countries, adopting a holistic and layered security strategy can be particularly effective. You are always just going to be upping the bar.  My two cents:
Direct IP and Geo-IP Blocking

Use .htaccess (on Apache) or web.config (on IIS) to block known problematic IP addresses
Complement this with Geo-IP blocking to automatically restrict access from specific countries that don't align with your audience

Enhance phpBB's Security Settings

Make full use of phpBB's anti-spam features
Adjust user permissions, implement CAPTCHAs, and activate user validation processes
Explore community-supported mods and plugins that enhance security against spam

Strengthen Server Response to Non-compliant Crawlers

Maintain an updated robots.txt as standard practice
For crawlers that ignore these directives, consider more aggressive tactics like issuing a 403 error based on their user-agent strings, directly from your server settings

Deploy a Web Application Firewall (WAF)

A WAF acts as a shield for your site, blocking malicious traffic and filtering out unwanted actions before they reach your server. Cloudflare is great at this.
This is effective against a range of threats, including spam and automated bots

Continuous Monitoring and Adaptation

Utilize analytics and server log analysis tools to monitor the effectiveness of your implemented strategies
Stay adaptive and ready to update your measures as necessary, responding to new patterns of attacks and threats

By integrating these methods, you create a comprehensive defense mechanism that not only addresses current issues but also prepares you for future challenges.

I'm  using the stopforumspam API and also using a form of geo-location based on Country names in certain pages/forms, but I'd like to block some of the more prevalent spammers and crawlers entirely .. so even before they get to the site pages.

Just about any WAF (including mod_security) will do this. Personally I've used fail2ban in the past for this.
You didn't tell us anything about the platform/environment this is running in so I don't know if fail2ban will work for you. But the nice thing about fail2ban is you can configure it to use an mechanism you can script for applying the ban. The default is to block via iptables, but you could simply maintain a database and check this from PHP, or invoke an RPC end-point on a remote firewall.

It's a .NET website and phpBB forum. The website is managed through plesk and is on a shared hosted-service.

Best is mostly a matter of opinion.
Your options are in two broad categories, both with advantages and disadvantages.
1. Block IP's in the network layer
This are approaches like host-based firewalls, network firewalls, null routing, network ACL's, security groups etc.

advantages

computationally cheap, doesn't require (much) resources from the webserver

most secure as all packets from the blocked IP-address (range) will be blocked and can't even reach the web service anymore



disadvantages

such a block is absolute. A blocked site visitor will get a TCP/IP error like "connection" refused or "connection time-out", but you can't display a "your IP-address is banned due to abuse or other reason" user-friendly error message.
When a server hosts multiple sites, the blocked IP-address will be banned from all of them.



2. Block IP's in the application layer
These are approaches leveraging  security settings in the web server, the web application or a HTTP protocol aware "application" firewall or similar. Also a Content Delivery Network and their security policies can be included in this category.

advantages

allows for fine grained access controls - for example do allow access to the home page, but block access to admin/interactive sections of a site


disadvantages

can be much more complex to maintain
unwanted site visitors are restricted but not fully blocked. You limit their avenues of abuse, but every request from a "blocked" visitor will need to be evaluated and that still takes up resources and can  allow some forms of abuse to continue and succeed.




Approaches are often combined.
Leverage a CDN for protection at the HTTP level and configure a firewall policy that denies direct access, allows only traffic originating from your CDN (and monitoring) to prevent direct connections to your server that by-pass the CDN.

As there can be many non-malicious and well behaved site vistors behind the the same IPv4 IP-address often sites don't block IP-addresses but spend time and effort on detecting and admitting valid users with things like CAPTCHA's and other techniques instead.

I've noticed one site I tried to block using IIS Deny tables got through. They could I guess be spoofing the IP address I see, so I've added this one to web.config and .htaccess and will monitor the progress.
I'm surprised they got past IIS !!
